# Dolphin Search Toolbar is missing its text field. How can I get it back?

Tags: kubuntu, search, dolphin

A while ago, my Search Toolbar bar went missing in dolphin.

I'm referring to the Search Toolbar found under Settings>Toolbars Shown>Search Toolbar. I used to sit at the very top right corner of the window.

If the search toolbar is checked for view/unhide, the toolbar looks to activate something, as there is a slight shift in the interface buttons, but the text field is gone from the toolbar.

I tried reconfiguring with dpkg, purging and reinstalling, etc.

I left it alone as I thought it would be fixed in an update, but today I upgraded dolphin and it's still gone. This appears to be a 4.6 bug or something.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Dolphin has a search bar?

Comment: I just tested the latest Dolphin (from ppa) and when I click find the find bar opens...

Comment: @Roland - Yes dolphin has, or at least had a search bar. It is not the find bar that appears when you go to edit>find. It's also not the filter bar summoned with ctrl+i. The search bar is shown or hidden usuallu by checking/unchecking [Settings>Toolbars Shown>Search Toolbar]. It's awesome because it's integrated with nepomuk/strigi so it's super fast, or at least it used to be awesome.

Comment: I don't see any of that in the latest Dolphin. I think you might be using the one from the ppa. In such a case you would have to choose to search everywhere and not just that folder.

Comment: @Roland - so when you go in the menu bar to Settings>Toolbars Shown> there is no "Search Toolbar" checkable entry?

Comment: exactly what I mean...

Comment: sorry, i only asked again because i didn't really understand where the second part of your comment came from? - "In such a case you would have to choose to search everywhere and not just that folder." i'm not sure what that is referring to; i'm not having problems in that department and i thought i may have miscommunicated the actual problem. in any case, i'm using the beta backport ppa's and for me it's still there. maybe in a later version you're using they removed the menu entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other people seem to have the same problem.

http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=202&t=91646.

issue #8 on the first post

UPDATE:
they did remove the search toolbar. the option was showing even after updated, but after i deleted my dolphin folder in /.kde (and it generated a new one), the option disappeared.